# regularity; elliptic pde

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, regularity

Consider $N \ge 3$ a sequence of solutions $u^m$ to

$$-\Delta u^m(x) - \frac{\alpha u^m_{x_N}(x)}{x_N+\epsilon_m} = f^m(x) \quad \mbox{ in } B_2^+$$ with $ u^m=0$ on $ \partial B_2^+$  (here $B_R^+:=\{ x \in\Bbb R^N: |x|<R, x_N>0\}$).   Here $ \alpha>0$ with a range (which I am not specifying here... but could be important because of kernel considerations) and $ \epsilon_m>0$.

**Question/Goal.**
Assume we know $ | \nabla u^m(x)| \le 1$ and we know $ |f^m(x) | \le C$ (independent of $m$) and $ 0<\epsilon_m \rightarrow 0$.  Does there exist some $C_1>0$ (indepedent of $m$) such that
$$
\| u^m\|_{C^{1,\delta}(B_1^+)} \le C_1\quad  (\text{for some }\delta>0)?$$

This question is coming from some problem I am looking at after blow up analysis and this problem is close to one of the cases that I am having trouble handling.
Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit.  Added November 26.** After renormalizing the smooth solutions lets assume
$$ \frac{ | \nabla u^m(x)- \nabla u^m(y)|}{|x-y|^\delta} \le 1$$ and there is $x_m, y_m$ such that this quantity is greater than or equal $ \frac{1}{2}$.  If $ |x_m - y_m|$ is bounded away from zero then there is a contradiction.  Lets assume $y^m_N \ge x^m_N$ and we can assume $ x^m_N \rightarrow 0$ (otherwise again I think i can get a contradiction).   Using a blow up argument approach I think I can again arrive at a contradiction provided we have something like
$$ (y^m-x^m) \cdot e_N \ge C_0 |x^m-y^m|$$ (here $e_N$ the $N$ unit vector...so $y^m$ must lie in a vertical cone with vertex at $x$ and the cone must not be a full half space but smaller).

So with this in mind I am now interested in what kind of methods i can use to estimate the quantity
$$ \frac{| u_y(x_1,0) - u_y(x_2,0)|}{|(x_1,0)-x_2,0)|^\delta}$$ which is just the extreme case of the case I don't know how to handle.  Any comments would be greatly appreciated.  Also maybe the estimate I want is just plain false.  If its false can it be made true if we add some more smoothness to $ f^m$ ?

Comment: I guess you have $x_N$ at the denominator, in the first formula.

Comment: yes,  that is $ x_N$ in bottom;  i will edit.

Comment: Then the ratio can be estimated in $L^p$ norm by the Hardy inequality, by that of the gradient, uniformly in $\epsilon$. Moving it to the rhs you get $\Delta u_m=g_m$ with $g_m$ uniformly bounded. You can use $L^p$ estimated with $p>N$ to get a bound in $W^2_p$ and then in $C^{1,\delta}$.

Comment: I am a bit confused.  Do you mean to apply the p version of a boundary Hardy inequality like $ \int_\Omega | \nabla  \psi|^p dx \ge C_p \int_\Omega \delta(x)^{-p} | \psi|^p dx$ for all $ \psi=0$ on the boundary? (here $\delta$ is the distance to the boundary).   Note that term in the pde with the distance function has a derivaitve and so I don't see how to apply this inequality;  one could try and apply a higher order one ...but)

Comment: I would just estimate $u/x_N$ by $\nabla u$ in the sup-norm (I only use here that $u$ vanishes for $x_N=0$) and move to the RHS. I assume that you have already a solution.

Comment: i am still confused... isn't the term $ \frac{u_{x_N}}{x_N}$ so i don't see how the inequality helps

Comment: I am sorry! I did not notice the derivative with respect to $x_N$. Now it is another story and understand your previous comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116160/discussion-between-giorgio-metafune-and-math604).